# POST value array page to page wordpress

Tags: php, forms

I have a array `$excel_arr[$start]["B"]`, which is inserted into the input form value

**in main.php :**

```
<input type="text"  name="service" value="<?php echo $excel_arr[$start]["B"]; ?> ">
```

And display like [image: here]

**in handler.php :**

```
if(isset($_POST['service']) {
    $service = $_POST["service"];
    echo $service;
}
```

It always shows the last array value, not the value I choose
How to display the value I just selected ?

Eg: I click submit service1, then display service1

Sorry if the question already exists, I've tried it but it's hard to understand

Comment: can you show your html form ?

Comment: Do you have several forms?

Comment: Is the value in `$excel_arr[$start]["B"]` also an array? If you you cannot post an array of values like that. Please read [How do I create arrays in a HTML <form>?](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) in the PHP documentation